# Water mark in register form using mvc4/razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, registration, watermark

How to get the layout similar to the image below used by stackoverflow using mvc4/razor views. The watermark dissppears only after a text is entered. Not while focussing on the textbox[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placeholders are a client-side feature, and has nothing to do with the server-side platform you're using.

In HTML5, you can use the `placeholder=""` attribute, like so:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First name" />
```

In ASP.NET MVC, you can add the attribute like so:

```
Html.InputFor( m => m.FirstName, new { placeholder="First name" } )
```

IE8 does not support placeholders, but you can emulate them with a number of jQuery and Mootools add-ons that replicate the functionality.

Comment: Upload problems.I updated the question with image.
Thank you so much for the placeholder help..